# Sort documents by words order in query

Tags: solr

can you tell me how to sort result of documents in Solr by order of words which are in query?

For instance if I enter to query 2 words `milk` and `chocolate` I want boosted documents which contains these words in same order.

In my query:
`http://localhost:8983/solr/product/select?defType=edismax&fl=*%2C%20score&q.op=AND&q=chocolate+milk&qf=title_token%5E10`

you can see that I have query `chocolate milk` and results of that query is :

```
{
  id: 3346664,
  title: "Milk with chocolate",
  _version_: 1648030883251224600,
  score: 79.53341
},
{
  id: 8754567,
  title: "Chocolate of Milk",
  _version_: 1648030883402219500,
  score: 79.53341
},
{
  id: 345428,
  title: "Delicious Thins Milk Chocolate",
  _version_: 1648030884582916000,
  score: 74.86635
}
```

As you can see my first 2 documents has same `score` but first is document where matched words order is not same like words in my query. Can you tell me how to boost documents which match query words order? Thank you.

My title token field has this configuration:

```
<fieldType name="text_token" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pf2` and `pf3` parameters to the edismax query parser:

> **The pf2 Parameter**
>
> A multivalued list of fields with optional weights, based on pairs of word shingles.
>
> **The pf3 Parameter**
>
> A multivalued list of fields with optional weights, based on triplets of word shingles. Similar to pf, except that instead of building a phrase per field out of all the words in the input, it builds a set of phrases for each field out of each triplet of word shingles.

A shingle is two words combined, i.e. "Chocolate Milk". You also want to add a stopwordfilter, so that `of` gets removed from the token stream.

```
pf2=title^5
```

.. will apply a 5x boost to those where the words from your query appear after each other.

You can also add an explicit shingle filter which combines sets of tokens when you're indexing, and then apply a boost to that field.

Comment: This is how my query looks like now: /solr/core_name/select?defType=edismax&fl=*%2Cscore&pf2=title%5E30&q=chocolate%20milk&qf=title_token&stopwords=true

I set into pf2 field this title^30, I also tried add shingle filter to index analyzer and next into query analyzer as well, but I still have same result. Document with title `Chocolate of Milk` still not first

Comment: Use the `debug=all` setting to see how the score is being affected. The stopfilter will need to be present when indexing to remove `of` between the words for example. You'll also need to reindex after making any changes to the index analyzer.